# Need text values from non-nodes in XML response

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I have an API reply in XML format as follows:

```
 <SearchReply>
      <Status>
           SUCCESS
      </Status>
      <Itinerary>
         <Ticket>
              Boston
         </Ticket>
         <Price>
              10.00
         </Price>
      <Contract>
         A
      <Contract>
      <Contract
         B
       </Contract> 
 </SearchReply>
```

I can walk through the Itinerary nodes all day long and gather all the data.

let's say the XML reply is in a variable `doc`. `doc.text()` would contain the entire reply. `doc.Contracts.text()` winds up containing `AB`. I want to gather `A` then `B` and so on and put them in an `arraylist` alphabetically and for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I can't do anything with `AB` because those Contract values could be a string of ANY length so there is no way to parse it.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick (I corrected some of parsing issues in the XML, which I assume don't exist in the real XML). The call to `sort` will sort things lexicographically rather than alphabetically per se.

```
def contracts = new XmlSlurper().parseText(''' <SearchReply>
      <Status>
           SUCCESS
      </Status>
      <Itinerary>
         <Ticket>
              Boston
         </Ticket>
         <Price>
              10.00
         </Price>
      </Itinerary>
      <Contract>
         B
      </Contract>
      <Contract>
         A
       </Contract> 
 </SearchReply>''').Contract
                   .collect { it.text().trim() }
                   .sort()

assert contracts == ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: One other part of the question, how would I sort those strings alphabetically. If I convert to a list of strings then back to a string it would look awful.  [B, A, C, T, F] and then [[B,  A,  C,  T,  F]]
 and then [ A,  B, C , F], T] which is all messed up with the old brackets/

Comment: I updated the answer to include a call to `sort()`, which I believe is what you're looking for, correct?